# How to update a column with picture and display in table using select statement?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to `update` a field named `picture` in my table using the following query

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET
        photo = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN pg_read_binary_file('picture_name.jpg')::bytea end
       where id = 1;
```

Results shows that the task is done but when i tried to run select query it results a empty column. please give me a solution

I have stored my picture in  `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/data` this place.

Comment: What's the point of `CASE id WHEN 1 THEN`? You already selected the row with that id only.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty column"? A `NULL` value? An empty `bytea`? Something else?

Comment: What result do you get from `SELECT pg_read_binary_file('picture_name.jpg');`?

Comment: #Bergi I will input 23 data so i made this "CASE id WHEN 1 THEN".  I am not getting the image in select result output